# Finding the minimum from a nested list using recursion

Tags: python, nested-lists, minimum

I am trying to write a function to find the minimum value of a nested list. I have written code but get the error that I cannot use < between an integer and a list. Any ideas? I cannot use any built-in functions.

```
def minimumVal(Y):
   if len(Y) == 1:
      return Y[0]
   minimum = Y[0]
   if minimum < minimumVal(Y[1:]):
      return minimum
   else:
      return minimumVal(Y[1:])
```

Comment: Do you have an example of a nested list that throws an error? For instance, does the nested list have to be a list of lists, or can it be a list of ints and lists? If the second, you'll need to check the type of each element before proceeding, which seems to violate the restriction you can't use any built-in functions.

Comment: Please post your real code.  There is an obvious typo in `if minimum < minimumVal)Y[1:]):`.

Comment: @aschultz, the list is all integers, such as  [1, 2, 4, 5, [6, 8]]

Comment: @JohnGordon This is my real code, sorry for the typo, since we are not able to copy and paste code in here I made an error..

Comment: _we are not able to copy and paste code in here_ What?  Of course you can. What is stopping you?

Comment: @JohnGordon sorry, maybe I read the instructions wrong when posting the question. I thought we were unable to. Thanks for clarifying. The typo has been updated though

Comment: If you have a nested list such as `[[1,2,5]]`, the outer list contains only one element -- the inner list.  So the statement `if len(Y) == 1` will be true, and you end up returning the whole inner list, which causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to collapse the list with itertools but since you can't use built in functions, here's a scrappy method that works:

```
l = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, [3, 4, 5, 10], [15, 4, 9, 8]]
minimum = []
for sublist in l:
    try:
        for num in sublist:
            if len(minimum) == 0:
                minimum.append(num)
            else:
                if num < minimum[0]:
                    minimum[0] = num
    except:
        if len(minimum) == 0:
            minimum.append(sublist)
        else:
            if sublist < minimum[0]:
                minimum[0] = num

print(minimum[0])
```

> output: 2

if you can't use len(), here's another option with more tries/excepts:

```
l = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, [3, 4, 5, 10], [15, 4, 9, 8]]
minimum = []
for sublist in l:
    try:
        for num in sublist:
            try:
                if num < minimum[0]:
                    minimum[0] = num
            except IndexError:
                    minimum.append(num)
    except:
        try:
            if sublist < minimum[0]:
                minimum[0] = sublist
        except IndexError:
                minimum.append(sublist)

print(minimum[0])
```

> output: 2

Last option, if you can't use the built in function for append you can do this:

```
l = [3, 4, 5, 6, 2, [3, 4, 5, 10], [15, 4, 9, 8]]
minimum = ['place holder']
for sublist in l:
    try:
        for num in sublist:
            if minimum[0] != 'place holder':
                if num < minimum[0]:
                    minimum[0] = num
            else:
                    minimum[0] = num
    except:
        if minimum[0] != 'place holder':
            if sublist < minimum[0]:
                minimum[0] = sublist
        else:
                minimum[0] = sublist

print(minimum[0])
```

> output: 2

Comment: Hm, I think that's ok, because the original post has len. However, if you want to avoid using len, theh instead of "if len(minimum)" you could put "if minimum[0] == whatever" in your try blocks, and I think that would fix it.

Comment: @aschultz oh I like that idea, I also added another option that I thought of that doesn't len() that's kind of similar in thought. I figured the len() was alright because the original code had it too, but just to be sure